# Dynamically Importing Local and Remote Files

Tags: javascript, webpack, progressive-web-apps

## Background

I am currently building a Progressive Web Application (PWA) that has a rather odd localisation infrastructure. It has two elements:

- Locally defined translations (defined in the project repo)
- Remotely defined translations (statically stored in a CDN)

The way this needs to work, in theory, is quite simple:

1. Detect the locale
2. Import the local translations for the locale
3. Import the remote translations for the locale
4. Combine the objects
5. Provide them to the application

## The Problem(s)

This raises a few issues;

- How do I dynamically import only the the necessary 'local' translations?
- How will webpack know to bundle the local translations if the module/file name is dynamic?
- How do I dynamically import only the the necessary 'remote' translations?

## What I have tried

I currently have the following file structure:

```
/i18n
│   index.js
│
└───/translations
│   │
│   └───/en
│   │   │   index.js
│   │   │   meta.json
│   │   │   ...
│   │
│   └───/es
│   │   │   index.js
│   │   │   meta.json
│   │   │   ...
```

My intention is as follows:

- `/i18n/index.js` - perform the initial setup and dynamic loading of the necessary translations
- `/i18n/translations/XX/index.js` - gather and export all of the translation `json` files within the `XX` directory

I haven't managed to get very far with this as I'm not entirely sure how best to implement it but this is what I have so far:

**`/i18n/index.js`** - set up the localisation

```
// Determine the locale...
const locale = 'XX' // For example purposes

const translations = {};

// Import the local translations
// IS THIS THE RIGHT WAY TO DO THIS?
translations.local = require(`./translations/${locale}/index.js`);

// Import the remote translations here...
// Maybe use importScripts() but I am fairly certain this is 
// only available in the service worker...
// HOW CAN THIS BE DONE?
translations.remote = '';

translations.combined = Object.assign(translations.local, translations.remote);
```

**`/i18n/translations/XX/index.js`** - for the local imports

```
export default {
    meta: require('./meta')
    // etc...
}
```

## My Question(s)

As outlined in the problem section, I'm am not entirely sure how to go about achieving what I need. Can anyone suggest how best to implement this?

*Feel free to suggest an alternative file structure if what I currently have is not good practice...*